# Handling http errors in retrofit and okhttp in android application

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2, okhttp

In my android application I have used retrofit and okhttp as shown in below code snippets. The application works well and I am not getting any error during testing and also on production but some times  **socket timeout exception**, **sslhandshake exceptions**, **unknown host exceptions** are being logged in by firebase crashalytics  as fatal exceptions, which means that application is being crashed when these exceptions are thrown. I have checked with our network team and they have double checked every thing at their end, but issue is still there.  Is there a way that I can catch all these exceptions to avoid any fatal crashes. Here is my implementaion

```
class CoreDataModule {

    @Provides
    fun provideOkHttpClient(): OkHttpClient {
        val interceptor = HttpLoggingInterceptor()
        interceptor.level = HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY
        val client = OkHttpClient().newBuilder()
            .connectTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .readTimeout(90, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
            .writeTimeout(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            client.addInterceptor(interceptor)
        }
        client.addInterceptor { chain ->
            val request = chain.request()
            val response = chain.proceed(request)
            response
        }
        return client.build()
    }


    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMoshi(): Moshi = Moshi.Builder().build()

    @Provides
    @Singleton
    fun provideMoshiConverterFactory(): MoshiConverterFactory =
        MoshiConverterFactory.create()
}
```

This is inside Appmodule class

```
@Singleton
    @Provides
    fun providemyappService(@appAPI okHttpClient: OkHttpClient, converterFactory: MoshiConverterFactory) =
        provideService(okHttpClient, converterFactory, myappApi::class.java)


    @appAPI
    @Provides
    fun providePrivateOkHttpClient(upstreamClient: OkHttpClient): OkHttpClient {
        return upstreamClient.newBuilder().build()
    }


    @Singleton
    @Provides
    fun provideRemoteDataSource(myappService: myappApi) = RemoteDataSource(myappService)

private fun createRetrofit(
        okhttpClient: OkHttpClient,
        converterFactory: MoshiConverterFactory
    ): Retrofit {
        return if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL_STAGE)
                .client(okhttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
                .build()
        } else {
            Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(okhttpClient)
                .addConverterFactory(converterFactory)
                .build()
        }
    }

    private fun <T> provideService(
        okhttpClient: OkHttpClient,
        converterFactory: MoshiConverterFactory, clazz: Class<T>
    ): T {
        return createRetrofit(okhttpClient, converterFactory).create(clazz)
    }
```

This is inside API end point interface

```
@POST("Validate/UserValidation")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    suspend fun validateUser(@Field("data") data: String): Response<ValidationResponse>
```

Here are some crash logs from firebase console

```
Fatal Exception: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: failed to connect to app.com.pk/123.123.123.124 (port 443) after 15000ms
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:191) (Note: Actual fqdn and ip replaced here)
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:127)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:201)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:520)
       at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:927)
       at okhttp3.internal.platform.AndroidPlatform.connectSocket(AndroidPlatform.java:73)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectSocket(RealConnection.java:246)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:166)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200)
       at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

This is another stacktrace

```
Fatal Exception: java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ECONNRESET (Connection reset by peer)
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:629)
       at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:591)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:487)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:37)
       at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:237)
       at okio.Okio$2.read(Okio.java:140)
       at okio.AsyncTimeout$2.read(AsyncTimeout.java:237)
       at okio.RealBufferedSource.indexOf(RealBufferedSource.java:358)
       at okio.RealBufferedSource.readUtf8LineStrict(RealBufferedSource.java:230)
       at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readHeaderLine(Http1Codec.java:215)
       at okhttp3.internal.http1.Http1Codec.readResponseHeaders(Http1Codec.java:189)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.createTunnel(RealConnection.java:376)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTunnel(RealConnection.java:219)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:160)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200)
       at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
```

SSL Handshake exception

```
Fatal Exception: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0x7fa29fd100: I/O error during system call, Connection reset by peer
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(NativeCrypto.java)
       at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:323)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:319)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:283)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:168)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:257)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200)
       at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Unknown host exception

```
Fatal Exception: java.net.UnknownHostException: Unable to resolve host "app.com.pk": No address associated with hostname Note:ACtual FQDN changed here
       at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:424)
       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
       at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
       at okhttp3.Dns$1.lookup(Dns.java:40)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.resetNextInetSocketAddress(RouteSelector.java:185)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.nextProxy(RouteSelector.java:149)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.RouteSelector.next(RouteSelector.java:84)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:214)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:135)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:114)
       at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:126)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147)
       at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121)
       at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:254)
       at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:200)
       at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

I am using retrofit_version = "2.6.0"

Comment: Would you like to update your Proguard rule? I mean does this happen when you build your app release version not debug?

Comment: This has nothing to do with proguard.

Comment: @kartooskhan i am also facing same problem . Did you find any solution ?

Comment: @Vivek In my case there was another instance of retrofit, used independently in some activities. Removing it fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Thanks @kartooskhan , For me it was due to slow internet . I change the value
 .readTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS) to  .readTimeout(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
Solved my problem